# Regex code in java code

Tags: java, regex

I have the following Regex: `[<>\\]|\p{C}`

How can I create as String with that in Java, the problem is in the Regex are two backslashes:

```
String reg="[<>\\]|\p{C}";   // this gets error  

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(reg);
```

Comment: What are your imput strings and what would you like the result to be? When asking regex questions - give a few examples on input and output

Comment: Escape a backslash with another backslash ...

Answer (score 4):

Just escape the backslash, with a backslash :

```
String reg="[<>\\\\]|\\p{C}";
```

Comment: Your first regex was correct.  When you write regexes in the form of Java string literals, you **always** have to use four backslashes to match one.  Metacharacters like `*` lose their special meanings inside character classes, but escape sequences like `\s` don't, so the backslash is always special.

Comment: Btw, you can just include the Unicode property in the character class `"[\\p{C}<>\\\\]"`